# How to get latest version of SAM-CLI on windows

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, aws-lambda, sam

I have latest node installed:

```
node --version
v14.15.0
```

I installed sam-cli from
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-install-windows.html

Then i ran following command
npm install -g aws-sam-local

When i run:

```
sam --version
```

I get following:

```
A newer version of the AWS SAM CLI is available!
Your version:   0.2.11
Latest version: 1.9.0
See https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-local for upgrade instructions
```

I am attempting to invoke aws lambda function locally like following:

```
sam local invoke
```

I get following output:

```
2020/11/11 22:24:18 Successfully parsed template.yml
2020/11/11 22:24:18 Connected to Docker 1.40
2020/11/11 22:24:18 Could not initiate nodejs14.15 runtime: unsupported runtime
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem was i somehow installed 2 versions of sam-cli. I just deleted both from C:\Program Files\Amazon and reinstalled using msi from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-install-windows.html.

After this i was getting command not found when running

```
sam --version
```

Finally found that

```
sam.cmd --version
```

worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that your CLI version does not not support node v14.15.0.

I would suggest upgrading your CLI or downgrading your node version, depends on what you want to do.

Comment: So i have tried updating CLI version from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-install-windows.html but still shows version 0.2.11. Basically just want to be able to upgrade to version 1.9.0. Note that i am using windows.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue.
My sam version was SAM CLI, version 1.2.0.

Upgraded to SAM CLI, version 1.35.0 and issue got resolved.